# How to make VSCode recognize global component in Vue?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, visual-studio-code

### Hello, I have a project:

#### Vite -> Vue 3 -> Typescript (I use Volar for .vue sytax)

And I've made a global component **Icon** because it's used almost everywhere so i can just type it without importing the component. Problem is that VSCode think it's some mistake (without import).

The component works good.
It's imported to vue app in **main.ts** like this:

```js
// registration of global component <Icon />
import IconComponent from './components/ui/icon/IconComponent.vue'
app.component('Icon', IconComponent)
```

Any idea how could I tell VSCode ***"hey this is a global component, so don't mark it as mistake in other .vue files"***? **:)**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### I think I've found the answer so I'll post it here.

On [Volar github](https://github.com/johnsoncodehk/volar) there is:

###### *Define Global Components*

*"Local components, Built-in components, native HTML elements Type-Checking is available with no configuration.
For Global components, you need to define GlobalComponents interface, for example:"*

```js
// components.d.ts

// declare module '@vue/runtime-core' works for vue 3
// declare module 'vue' works for vue2 + vue 3
declare module 'vue' {
  export interface GlobalComponents {
    RouterLink: typeof import('vue-router')['RouterLink']
    RouterView: typeof import('vue-router')['RouterView']
  }
}

export {}
```